# Replace values between certain characters

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to replace a values between `OFFSET` and `ROWS` in a string.
I'm using the below regex and it doesn't work.

```
 string strValue = "OFFSET NUMBER ROWS"
 string strIndex = "5";
 strValue  = Regex.Replace(strValue , @"(?<=OFFSET)(\w+?)(?=ROWS)", strIndex);
```

So my desired result will be like

```
OFFSET 5 ROWS
```

Can anyone help or suggest what's wrong with this regex as it doesn't replace values.

Comment: You do not match the whitespace chars, use `@"(?<=OFFSET\s*)\w+(?=\s*ROWS)"`. Also, `string strIndex = 5;` must be written as `string strIndex = "5";` and do not forget `;` at the end of the command.

Comment: What does "Doesn't work" mean? Does it do nothing? Does it throw an exception? Does it output the wrong string? "Doesn't work" isn't a helpful description of a problem.

Comment: When constructing a reg ex pattern for replacement you should first check, whether your pattern matches at all. You can use `IsMatch` for that job:
`Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(strValue, @"(?<=OFFSET)(\w+?)(?=ROWS)"));`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - It worked! Thanks

Comment: @vicky I explained the fix in the answer and added an alternative solution.

Comment: @vicky actually it is an almost well posted question. But please be in future a little more precise in your problem description: "it doesn't work." as far away from informative. Still... have an upvote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex related problem here is that you have not accounted for whitespace chars on both ends of the `NUMBER`. Add `\s*` or `\s+` to account for them.

Use

```
string strValue = "OFFSET NUMBER ROWS";
string strIndex = "5";
strValue  = Regex.Replace(strValue , @"(?<=OFFSET\s*)\w+(?=\s*ROWS)", strIndex);
Console.Write(strValue); // => OFFSET 5 ROWS
```

Here,

- `(?<=OFFSET\s*)` is a positive lookbehind requiring `OFFSET` and 0+ whitespace chars  immediately to the left of the current location
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `(?=\s*ROWS)` -  is a positive lookahead requiring 0+ whitespace chars  immediately to the right of the current location and then `ROWS` substring.

Alternatively, use capturing groups with backreferences in the replacement pattern:

```
strValue = Regex.Replace(strValue , @"(OFFSET\s*)\w+(\s*ROWS)", $"${{1}}{strIndex}$2");
```

See the [C# online demo](https://ideone.com/nvOl6u).

The variation of the solution with the capturing group is a bit tricky since the first backreference is followed with a digit, and thus you cannot use a regular `$1` syntax, you must use an unambiguous form, `${1}`.